# Is a requires expression an atom when normalizing constraints?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to make sure I properly understand the constraint normalization process since cppreference is slightly fuzzy on this topic.

It seems that during the normalization, anything that is inside of a `requires` expression is always considered an atom, no matter how specific/complex.

This seems to be supported by the different handling of:

```
template<typename T>
concept Decrementable = requires(T t) { --t; };

template<typename T>
concept RevIterator = Decrementable<T> && requires(T t) { *t; };

template<typename T>
concept RevIterator2 = requires(T t) { --t; *t; };
```

Where `Decrementable < RevIterator` but `Decrementable` and `RevIterator2` are not ordered.

So, is this correct? Or can someone point me to the specific part of the standard that talks about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct. For subsumption (what you denote by `<`) to occur, there has to be a certain relationship between the normal forms of the constraint expression. And if one examines the constraint normalization process:

> **[temp.constr.normal]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.constr.normal#1) The normal form of an expression E is a constraint that is defined as follows:
>
> - The normal form of an expression `( E )` is the normal form of `E`.
> - The normal form of an expression `E1 || E2` is the disjunction of the normal forms of `E1` and `E2`.
> - The normal form of an expression `E1 && E2` is the conjunction of the normal forms of `E1` and `E2`.
> - The normal form of a concept-id `C<A1, A2, ..., An>` is the normal form of the constraint-expression of `C`, after substituting `A1`, `A2`, ..., `An` for `C`'s respective template parameters in the parameter mappings in each atomic constraint. If any such substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.
>   [ ... ]
> - The normal form of any other expression `E` is the atomic constraint whose expression is E and whose parameter mapping is the identity mapping.

one sees that logical AND expressions, logical OR expressions, and concept-ids are the only expressions that get "broken down". Every other sort of expression pretty much forms its own atomic constraint, including a `requires` expression like `requires(T t) { --t; *t; }`.

Answer (score 1):

The [rules of constraint expression normalization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.normal#1) act recursively top-down. If an expression is not a conjunction/disjunction of two expressions, is not a parenthesized expression, and is not a concept name, then it is an atomic constraint expression. A `requires` expression is not one of those exceptions, so it is an atomic constraint expression.